# Prove the intersection of two spans is equal to zero

Tags: linear-algebra

If V is a vector space. Suppose S is contained in V and that $S = S_1 \cup S_2$ and that $S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset$, and that S is linearly independent. Prove $\operatorname{Span}(S_1) \cap \operatorname{Span}(S_2) = \{0\}$.

I get as far as S is independent and the union of S1 and S2 is equal to S. However, I get stuck on showing how exactly Span(s1) and Span(S2) have zero as part of their intersection. I know S1 is not equal to S2 because S1 ∩ S2 = emptyset  but how would you go about showing that their spans only have zero in common? or am I misunderstanding the question? Any thoughts would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Every non-empty subset of a vector space has the zero vector as part of its span because the span is closed under linear combinations, i.e. a linear combination of members of the span is also a member of the span.  If you just multiply one vector in the set by the scalar $0$, you get the $0$ vector, so that's a linear combination of the members of the set.

Therefore the zero vector is a member of both spans, and hence a member of their intersection.

Next there is the problem of showing that the spans have **only** the zero vector as a common member.  Let's suppose some non-zero vector were a member of both spans.  Then that non-zero vector would be linear combination of members of $S_1$, and also of members of $S_2$.  Since $S_1$ does not intersect $S_2$, that means it is expressed as a linear combination of the members of $S_1 \cup S_2$ in **two different ways**.  But that would mean $S_1\cup S_2$ is not a linearly independent set.

Comment: Wow that makes sense! Thanks I've been at this for hours!